# Finding if function is const

Tags: c++, c++14, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, type-traits

I am trying to find if a lambda or a free function is const using C++14 metaprogramming.

My current strategy is to use the `std::is_reference`, `std::is_pointer` and `std::is_const` on each of the arguments. (Currently ignoring global variables...)

So the type object that checks looks something like this...

```
template <typename F>
struct is_const_func: public function_traits<decltype(&F::operator())> {};

template <typename ClassType, typename ReturnType, typename... Args> 
struct is_const_func<ReturnType (ClassType::*)(Args...)> {
  static const std::tuple<std::is_reference<Args>...> ref;
  static const std::tuple<std::is_pointer<Args>...> ptr;
  static const std::tuple<std::is_const<Args>...> con;
  static const bool value = ? // Reduce(&&, (!ref && !ptr) || con)
}
```

I want to know how to implement the `value`. Basically I want to take the ith element from each of the tuples and compute `(!ref[i] && !ptr[i]) || con[I]` and reduce the resulting tuple with `&&`, all at compile time.

How do I implement this? Is there a better way to make this check?

Comment: What does mean for a free function to be const?

Comment: In this case, I am checking if all the pointers and references passed in as arguments are `const` qualified. This is not sufficient for the function to not change state of the program, but I am assuming no global variables are accessed/changed in the function.

Comment: What would you even do with such a trait? You can't really ever get this right - in addition to global state, a passed on `T const*` could still have a `mutable` member that gets modified, etc.

Comment: "*I am assuming no global variables are accessed/changed in the function*" - there is no way for the compiler to validate that. A free function can't be `const` qualified, and may access globals other than its own parameters. A class method can be `const` qualified to prevent it from altering class data members (its `this` pointer is `const`), but it can still access globals and non-const members of other objects. In short, a function/method having `const` parameters does not make it truly `const` everywhere. What you are asking for requires a static analysis tool instead.

Comment: As to the narrow question asked, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction. But I agree with others that this is not a useful trait to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First find an implementation of C++17 std apply.

Next write `all_of` as a `constexpr` template functions.

Next, write

```
struct all_of_t{
  constexpr all_of_t(){}
  template<class...Bs>
  constexpr bool operator()(Bs...bs)const{ return all_of(bs...); }
};
```

Finally:

```
static const std::tuple<std::integral_constant<bool,
  (!std::is_reference<Args>{}&&!std::is_pointer<Args>{})||std::is_const<Args>{}>...
> arg_state;
static const bool value = apply( all_of_t, arg_state );
```

each step should be easy to search for on SO.

Comment: Rather than writing `all_of` as `constexpr` functions, there's a nice efficient solution of `template <bool... Bs> constexpr bool all_of_v = Bs && ...;` in C++17, or `template <bool... Bs> constexpr bool all_of_v = std::is_same<bools<true, Bs...>, bools<Bs..., true>>::value;` where `bools` is a type like `template <bools... Bs> struct bools {};`

Comment: @justin I would make those integral constant values myself not bool constants